# Как задать свой путь cahe path selenium webdriver firefox c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Мне нужно, чтоб при повторном заходе кэш (куки и тп) загружался заного
Пытался так :

```
     FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"D:\сacheFirefox",false);
     IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
     MessageBox.Show(profile.ProfileDirectory);
```

но папка `D:\сacheFirefox` пуста, а `MessageBox` выводит путь в темп папке, но даже если перейти по нему, то конечной папки не окажется (`anonymous....`), там, где и должен быть сохранен кэш. Можете помочь ?